# npm cors package not working

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm having trouble accessing my server even with the npm `cors` package installed.

```
import Express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

/**********************

 SERVER CONFIG

 *********************/

import serverConfig from './config';
import auth from './routes/v1/auth.routes'

// Initialize Express
const app = new Express();

// DB Setup
mongoose.connect(serverConfig.mongoUrl, error => {
  if (error) {
    throw new Error('Please make sure Mongodb is installed and running!');
  } else {
    console.log(`MongoDB is running on port ${serverConfig.mongoUrl}`);
  }
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

/**********************

 MIDDLEWARE

 *********************/

app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080'],
    credentials: true
  }));
app.use(compression());
// Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property.
// This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
/**********
 MULTIPARTY

 - It will not create a temp file for you unless you want it to.
 - Counts bytes and does math to help you figure out the Content-Length of the final part.
 - You can stream uploads to s3 with aws-sdk, for example.
 - Less bugs. This code is simpler, has all deprecated functionality removed, has cleaner tests, and does not try to do anything beyond multipart stream parsing.
 *********/
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: false }));
app.use('/api/v1', auth);

/**********************

 START EXPRESS SERVER

 *********************/

app.listen(serverConfig.port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${serverConfig.port}`);
});
```

**Router file**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import * as AuthController from './controllers/auth.controller';

import * as passportConfig from '../../utils/passport.config';
import Passport from 'passport';

// Since we are using tokens, we don't want passport to create a cookie-based session
const requireAuth = Passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }); // use after sign in or signed up
const requireSignin = Passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }); // before signin

const router = new Router();

/**********************

 AUTHENTICATION

 *********************/

// Sign Up New User
// Don't need middleware because signup producers token
router.route('/signup').post(AuthController.signup); 
// Sign in Existing User
// Need to provide token after localStrat
router.route('/signin').post(requireSignin, AuthController.signin); 

export default router;
```

[image: cors error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also define your origin url inside cors function as,

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080'],
    credentials: true
}));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post the code for your api which you are trying to access?

Comment: I have updated my question above to include more of the server code :)

Comment: can you try accessing the above api using ``GET``. Does it work?

Comment: Found the issue. There was a conflict in localhost ports. That's why the cors error still came up. Your answer above got past the cors error in the question so I will mark it as an answer :) thank you!

Comment: What was the conflict in localhost ports?  I'm getting the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also facing similar issue. But no matter how many times I add app.use(cors({origin:['http://localhost:3000']})) or change header values, I still am stuck with the same issue. Can you suggest me something?