# CORS error while trying to register on my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fly

I'm new to the world of node.js and backend programmation, and i have a CORS error.
i already tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked for me.
I'm using fly.io as server.

`Acess to fetch at 'https://<MYFLY.IO URL>/register' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

in my code, i already have this :

```
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

also, i have this line that shows up when i click register :
`2023/07/06 - 16:29:39 | 404 | 910ns | 92.188.66.18 | OPTIONS /register`
(note : the register code worked well on localhost with nodemon)
Do someone have a solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm cors package not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220873/npm-cors-package-not-working)

Comment: @Mearaj OP clearly has the `cors` middleware already

Comment: https://community.fly.io/t/cors-issue-on-express-changes-do-not-take-effect/11668

Comment: @Phil, I am sorry, I misunderstood it, my mistake, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: @phil i tried this solution, unfortunately it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in fact, there is only with this localhost adress that it doesn't want to work. I tried building my app with expo go, and when i try to register, it doesn't show the CORS error. So, probleme solved ? well, i have another problem now, but i can't post my question here because it is not the same purpose.